# Defining an injection on the set of binary sequences

Tags: proof-explanation, real-numbers

I'm trying to solve the below problem from an old problem set, but I believe there may be an error in the problem.

> Show that the map $f: \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to [0,1]$ given by $f((a_i)) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{10^{i+1}}$ is injective.

It does not seem to me that this function is injective because there are real numbers with non-unique binary expansions. For example, $10.000 \ldots$ and $1.11 \ldots$ are equal to $2$. Since this function must map to $[0,1]$, I'm not able to think of a good example where injectivity fails, and I'm not sure if the nature of the codomain prevents this problem. But I think, regardless, if I have a binary expansion that is $1$ from some point onward, I can increment the prior digit, change all the $1$'s to $0$'s, and output the same real number, so I think the problem fails.

Is this indeed a problem preventing this map from being injective? Would it be fixed if we required, in defining the map, that we "choose" a binary expansion that isn't $1$ from any point onward?

Answer (score 1):

To have an injection you should require that there exist infinitely many terms of $\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ estrictly less than $b-1$, where $b$ is the number that you want to express as the sum, i.e. $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist $N\geq n$ such as $a_N\not =b-1$

Answer (score 1):

It's not binary expansions, but decimal expansions, because the terms of the infinite sum are $\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1}}$.

Therefore the problem of different expansions giving the same number occurs with $0.999...$, which won't occur because your digits are all $1$ or $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**The map is indeed injective**

You're confusing binary expansion with expansion in base 10. Here we're using an expansion in base 10 and the digits are never equal to 9. So the problem you mentioned in your last sentence can't occur.